# How to enable server side SSL for gRPC?

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, grpc

New to gRPC and couldn't really find any example on how to enable SSL on the server side.  I generated a key pair using openssl but it complains that the private key is invalid.

```
D0608 16:18:31.390303 Grpc.Core.Internal.UnmanagedLibrary Attempting to load native library "...\grpc_csharp_ext.dll"
D0608 16:18:31.424331 Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension gRPC native library loaded successfully.
E0608 16:18:43.307324 0 ..\src\core\lib\tsi\ssl_transport_security.c:644: Invalid private key.
E0608 16:18:43.307824 0 ..\src\core\lib\security\security_connector.c:821: Handshaker factory creation failed with TSI_INVALID_ARGUMENT.
E0608 16:18:43.307824 0 ..\src\core\ext\transport\chttp2\server\secure\server_secure_chttp2.c:188: Unable to create secure server with credentials of type Ssl.
```

Here's my code

```
var keypair = new KeyCertificatePair(
            File.ReadAllText(@"root-ca.pem"),
            File.ReadAllText(@"ssl-private.key"));
SslServerCredentials creds = new SslServerCredentials(new List<KeyCertificatePair>() {keypair});
Server server = new Server
{
    Services = { GrpcTest.BindService(new GrpcTestImpl()) },
    Ports = { new ServerPort("127.0.0.1", Port, creds) }
};
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Here's what I did.

Using [OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), generate certificates with the following:

```
@echo off
set OPENSSL_CONF=c:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg   

echo Generate CA key:
openssl genrsa -passout pass:1111 -des3 -out ca.key 4096

echo Generate CA certificate:
openssl req -passin pass:1111 -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj  "/C=US/ST=CA/L=Cupertino/O=YourCompany/OU=YourApp/CN=MyRootCA"

echo Generate server key:
openssl genrsa -passout pass:1111 -des3 -out server.key 4096

echo Generate server signing request:
openssl req -passin pass:1111 -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj  "/C=US/ST=CA/L=Cupertino/O=YourCompany/OU=YourApp/CN=%COMPUTERNAME%"

echo Self-sign server certificate:
openssl x509 -req -passin pass:1111 -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt

echo Remove passphrase from server key:
openssl rsa -passin pass:1111 -in server.key -out server.key

echo Generate client key
openssl genrsa -passout pass:1111 -des3 -out client.key 4096

echo Generate client signing request:
openssl req -passin pass:1111 -new -key client.key -out client.csr -subj  "/C=US/ST=CA/L=Cupertino/O=YourCompany/OU=YourApp/CN=%CLIENT-COMPUTERNAME%"

echo Self-sign client certificate:
openssl x509 -passin pass:1111 -req -days 365 -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out client.crt

echo Remove passphrase from client key:
openssl rsa -passin pass:1111 -in client.key -out client.key
```

*Change password 1111 to anything you like*

Server:

```
var cacert = File.ReadAllText(@"ca.crt");
var servercert = File.ReadAllText(@"server.crt");
var serverkey = File.ReadAllText(@"server.key");
var keypair = new KeyCertificatePair(servercert, serverkey);
var sslCredentials = new SslServerCredentials(new List<KeyCertificatePair>() { keypair }, cacert, false);

var server = new Server
{
    Services = { GrpcTest.BindService(new GrpcTestImpl(writeToDisk)) },
    Ports = { new ServerPort("0.0.0.0", 555, sslCredentials) }
};
server.Start();
```

Client:

```
var cacert = File.ReadAllText(@"ca.crt");
var clientcert = File.ReadAllText(@"client.crt");
var clientkey = File.ReadAllText(@"client.key");
var ssl = new SslCredentials(cacert, new KeyCertificatePair(clientcert, clientkey));
channel = new Channel("localhost", 555, ssl);
client = new GrpcTest.GrpcTestClient(channel);
```

*If "localhost" doesn't work, use the host name instead.*

Comment: IMPORTANT: replace %COMPUTERNAME% with domain name of server machine

If it has IP address only, and you cannot grant it domain name, try to
1) %COMPUTERNAME% = my-server
2) edit /etc/hosts at client machine and add line
111.111.111.111 my-server
where 111.111.111.111 is ip address of the server machine

Comment: @NikolayPakudin  After doing the above implementation getting below error in client, StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="DNS resolution failed". Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía You need to be able to make a DNS lookup on the server name from the client. In terms of Windows machines, you may execute `PING COMPUTERNAME`, but it may not resolve using DNS. As noted in Nikolays comment above, you then need to make sure `nslookup SERVERNAME` works on your client computers.

Comment: As a simple workaround, you can specify the ip address for the server, and add channel option to override the name of the server, so for instance: `var options = new List<ChannelOption> { new ChannelOption(ChannelOptions.SslTargetNameOverride, "ACTUAL-HOSTNAME") }; var channel = new Channel("1.2.3.4", 555, ssl, options);`

Comment: Your batch file mentions openssl.cfg. There is no such file in my system. What should be in it? (sample contents).

Answer (score 5):

If usage of Certificate Authority (CA) and Certificate Signing Request (CSR) is too sophisticated for your task, you can use self-signed certificates.

Let say, there is 1 server and 2 (or more) clients.

Execute at client1:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout client.key -out client.crt -days 3650 -subj '/CN=client1' # generate client1 cert and key
sudo bash -c 'echo "192.168.1.101 my.server" >> /etc/hosts' # create domain for server - if necessary only
scp client.crt server-user@my.server:/path/to/certs/client1.crt # copy public cert client1 to server machine
```

Execute at client2:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout client.key -out client.crt -days 3650 -subj '/CN=client2' # generate client2 cert and key
sudo bash -c 'echo "192.168.1.101 my.server" >> /etc/hosts' # create domain for server- if necessary only
scp client.crt server-user@my.server:/path/to/certs/client2.crt # copy public cert client2 to server machine
```

Execute at server:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.crt -days 3650 -subj '/CN=my.server' # generate server cert and key
scp server.crt client1-user@client1-addr:/path/to/certs # copy public cert server to client1 machine
scp server.crt client2-user@client2-addr:/path/to/certs # copy public cert server to client2 machine
cat client1.crt client2.crt > client.crt # combine client certs into the single file
```

Server code:

```
var clientCert = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(certPath, "client.crt"));
var serverCert = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(certPath, "server.crt"));
var serverKey = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(certPath, "server.key"));
var keyPair = new KeyCertificatePair(serverCert, serverKey);
var credentials = new SslServerCredentials(new List<KeyCertificatePair> { keyPair }, clientCert, true);

var server = new Server
{
    Services = { MyService.BindService(new MyAdminService()) },
    Ports = { new ServerPort("0.0.0.0", 54321, credentials) }
};
```

Client code:

```
var serverCert = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(_certPath, "server.crt"));
var clientCert = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(_certPath, "client.crt"));
var clientKey = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(_certPath, "client.key"));
var credentials = new SslCredentials(serverCert, new KeyCertificatePair(clientCert, clientKey));

var channel = new Channel("my.server:54321", credentials);    
var client = new MyService.MyServiceClient(channel);
```

**IMPORTANT!**

To use TLS certificates, use a domain name when generate server certificate.

Client certificates can use any unique string.

Domain name should contain at least 1 dot (.), e.g. `my.server` or `my.server.customzone`

If use top-level domain like `my-server`, it causes a long waiting to resolve it (for me it always about 76 seconds).

**Pros:**
- no need to generate CSR, pass it to machine with CA, sign it there and copy back to originating machine

**Cons:**
- adding new client requires adding certificate to server

Answer (score 2):

If you have tried what @qmo has suggested and still not working and you're getting the same error saying *"StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="DNS resolution failed"* I fixed it by adding a new record in my host file (located in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc for Windows).

```
127.0.0.1 DESKTOP-QNCI7UN
```

Where DESKTOP-QNCI7UN is the name of my machine. Then in the client I'm using:

```
channel = new Channel("DESKTOP-QNCI7UN", 50000, ssl);
```

By using "locahost" it was not working. So by using the machine name in the client + added record in the host file fixed the issue.