# TLS support for GRPC in C#

Tags: c#, grpc

I'm rather new to C#, and I need to use GRPC over TLS.

As a dry-run, I'm modifying the example provided in the [main grpc repo](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/) to use TLS. To do this, I found another SO question with what seemed like a good answer: [How to enable server side SSL for gRPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714558/how-to-enable-server-side-ssl-for-grpc). However, I get an error `Unhandled Exception: Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Connect Failed")` (full trace below).

I get the same error if I in the original, non-tls code, specify an incorrect port or just don't start the server. I'm using dotnet core on Ubuntu.

The important parts of the code are below, and also found in full on a fork on [github](https://github.com/zut/grpc/commit/3d0e76ef544fc69311e98f20d8ecae5334578d95).

Client:

```
  var cacert = File.ReadAllText(@"../ca.crt");
  var clientcert = File.ReadAllText(@"../client.crt");
  var clientkey = File.ReadAllText(@"../client.key");
  var ssl = new SslCredentials(cacert, new KeyCertificatePair(clientcert, clientkey));
  var channel = new Channel("localhost", 555, ssl);
  var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);

  String user = "you";

  var reply = client.SayHello(new HelloRequest {Name = user});
  Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply.Message);

  channel.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
  Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
  Console.ReadKey();
```

Server:

```
  var cacert = File.ReadAllText(@"../ca.crt");
  var servercert = File.ReadAllText(@"../server.crt");
  var serverkey = File.ReadAllText(@"../server.key");
  var keypair = new KeyCertificatePair(servercert, serverkey);
  var sslCredentials = new SslServerCredentials(new List<KeyCertificatePair>() {keypair}, cacert, false);

  var server = new Server
  {
    Services = {Greeter.BindService(new GreeterImpl())},
    Ports = {new ServerPort("0.0.0.0", 555, sslCredentials)}
  };
  server.Start();


  Console.WriteLine("Greeter server listening on port " + Port);
  Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the server...");
  Console.ReadKey();

  server.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
```

Full output of the programs:

```
$ cd GreeterClient
$ dotnet run -f netcoreapp1.0

Unhandled Exception: Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Connect Failed")
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg)
   at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Helloworld.Greeter.GreeterClient.SayHello(HelloRequest request, CallOptions options)
   at Helloworld.Greeter.GreeterClient.SayHello(HelloRequest request, Metadata headers, Nullable`1 deadline, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at GreeterClient.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

And server:

```
$ cd GreeterServer/
$ dotnet run -f netcoreapp1.0
Greeter server listening on port 50051
Press any key to stop the server...
```

Did I do some silly mistake, or does this not run on non-windows machines? Is there some way to debug the issue to figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is implementing Mutual TLS with self signed certs correctly - I was able to run it on windows netcore without any changes.

I did have to tweak the certificate generation script a little:

- Adding environment variable definition for `CLIENT-COMPUTERNAME`, used for the client `/CN` (Common Name)
- Adding a `-config` option to get rid of `unable to find 'distinguished_name' in config` error (might be a openssl on Windows thing)

I was able to reproduce the same error message that you had by deliberately mismatching the host that the client connects to (`127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`). So maybe you just need to regenerate your keys with e.g. `localhost` as the client's common name.

Comment: Yes, the name of the host you are connecting to needs to match the client channel target (so you might need to regenerate you certificate to make them match). You can get more insight by enabling more logging by setting the env variable GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug