# Java gRPC - TLS - how to set up mutual TLS on the client side?

Tags: security, ssl, https, grpc, grpc-java

I work on a software application that uses gRPC to establish a bi-directional stream between client and a server.

I'm looking for something similar to this ticket's answer only in java: [How to enable server side SSL for gRPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714558/how-to-enable-server-side-ssl-for-grpc)

I would like to configure my application so that they can choose what TLS scenario they want to use:

**Scenario 1**: plaintext (no encryption)

**Scenario 2**: Server-side TLS

**Scenario 3**: Mutual TLS

For TLS setups, I am using Java on non-Android environments, so I will only be considering the OpenSSL installed scenario using https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#openssl-statically-linked-netty-tcnative-boringssl-static

Configuring the **server side** seems pretty straight forward because it is documented quite well: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#mutual-tls

Here would be the steps for the corresponding TLS options:

**Sever-side configuration for Scenario 1**: Use `builder.usePlaintext`

**Sever-side configuration for Scenario 2**:  Add a `NettyServerBuilder.sslContext` built by SSL Context Builder with `GrpcSslContexts.forServer` and set the `cert chain` and `cert key` (and password if needed)

**Sever-side configuration for Scenario 3**:  Add a `NettyServerBuilder.sslContext` built by SSL Context Builder with `GrpcSslContexts.forServer` and set the `cert chain` and `cert key` (and password if needed), and also set a `trustManager` on the sslContextBuidler set to the trust cert file.

The server-side part is well documented which is excellent.

Now I want to configure a `NettyChannelBuilder` on the **client side**. The only thing I can find information on this is in this unit test: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/interop-testing/src/test/java/io/grpc/testing/integration/TlsTest.java

Here are the configurations I *think* are needed, but need to get confirmation on.

**Client-side configuration for Scenario 1**: Use `nettyChannelBuilder.usePlaintext(true)`. This will disable TLS on the netty channel to grpc.

**Client-side configuration for Scenario 2**: Set the sslContext using  `nettyChannelBuilder.negotiationType(NegotiationType.TLS).sslContext(GrpcSslContexts.configure(SslContextBuilder.forClient(), SslProvider.OPENSSL).build())`. This will configure the channel to communicate through TLS to grpc server using the default ciphers and application protocol configs.

**Client-side configuration for Scenario 3**: Set up TLS for the netty channel using  `nettyChannelBuilder.negotiationType(NegotiationType.TLS).sslContext(GrpcSslContexts.configure(SslContextBuilder.forClient(), SslProvider.OPENSSL).sslContextBuilder.trustManager(clientAuthCertFile)
.clientAuth(ClientAuth.OPTIONAL).build())` where `clientAuthCertFile` is the trust cert file and `ClientAuth.OPTIONAL` can also be `ClientAuth.REQUIRED` if you require mutual TLS.

Is there anything incorrect with my client-side configurations? Do I need any tweaks? I will add this as a PR to the security.md file after getting some blessing from the community on this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a hello world TLS PR to the grpc-java project here https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/pull/3992

the latest version of grpc-java as soon as this pr is merged will have a really nice working hello-world example. So all you have to do is git clone that project from master, and look at the example/README.md.

Comment: Do you have any example of gRPC using Mutual TLS using Java 12 ALPN ? Can you guide me on how to achieve this. Thanks