# how to use ssl certificates with gRPC and ASP Net Core 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc

I am rtying to configure the service to use a SSL certificate. I have read this post:

[How to enable server side SSL for gRPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714558/how-to-enable-server-side-ssl-for-grpc)

I guess this is the main code:

```
var cacert = File.ReadAllText(@"ca.crt");
var servercert = File.ReadAllText(@"server.crt");
var serverkey = File.ReadAllText(@"server.key");
var keypair = new KeyCertificatePair(servercert, serverkey);
var sslCredentials = new SslServerCredentials(new List<KeyCertificatePair>() { keypair }, cacert, false);

var server = new Server
{
    Services = { GrpcTest.BindService(new GrpcTestImpl(writeToDisk)) },
    Ports = { new ServerPort("0.0.0.0", 555, sslCredentials) }
};
server.Start();
```

The problem is that in my case, I don't start the service in this way, I am using kestrel, and the code is this:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
            {
                System.Net.IPAddress miAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("x.x.x.x");
                //options.Listen(miAddress, 5001, o => o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2);

                options.Listen(miAddress, 5001, l =>
                {
                    l.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
                    l.UseHttps();
                    });
            });
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

In this case, I don't have access to SslCredentials, so I can't create a new one.

How could I configure my ssl certificate using kestrel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post you linked to is for Grpc.Core, the grpc-dotnet implementation is configured differently.

This documentation and example should help:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/blob/dd72d6a38ab2984fd224aa8ed53686dc0153b9da/testassets/InteropTestsWebsite/Program.cs#L55

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1

(in another words, you can configure the certificates on the server side exactly the same way as you would for any other HTTP/2 server - there's nothing grpc specific in configuring the secure connections in ASP.NET Core).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you mistake authentication by certificates for SSL-data-encryption. In case you just want to encrypt the data channel, good practice is to use Kestrel:

```
   public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5005, configure => { configure.UseHttps(); configure.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2; });
        });
    });
```

The call to UseHttps() uses the internal ASP.NET Core’s trusted development certificate.

If you want to provide one yourself, use i.e. (or the other overloads):

```
public static ListenOptions UseHttps(this ListenOptions listenOptions, X509Certificate2 serverCertificate)
```

or in appsettings.json one of the following:

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
      },
      "HttpsInlineCertFile": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "<path to .pfx file>",
          "Password": "$CREDENTIAL_PLACEHOLDER$"
        }
      },
      "HttpsInlineCertAndKeyFile": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5002",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "<path to .pem/.crt file>",
          "KeyPath": "<path to .key file>",
          "Password": "$CREDENTIAL_PLACEHOLDER$"
        }
      },
      "HttpsInlineCertStore": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5003",
        "Certificate": {
          "Subject": "<subject; required>",
          "Store": "<certificate store; required>",
          "Location": "<location; defaults to CurrentUser>",
          "AllowInvalid": "<true or false; defaults to false>"
        }
      },
      "HttpsDefaultCert": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5004"
      }
    },
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
        "Path": "<path to .pfx file>",
        "Password": "$CREDENTIAL_PLACEHOLDER$"
      }
    }
  }
}
```