# HTTP2 .Net Framework issues with gRPC

Tags: http, ssl, f#, grpc, channel

I need to use gRPC for bi-directional streaming, where the client is a .Net Framework project, which due to legacy stuff, can't be upgraded to .NET5+.

When reading microsoft documentation, i can see that the WinHttpHandler should be used (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/netstandard?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

But i seem to have an issue using SSL with this setup, does anybody have a suggestion to what can be done to solve this issue?

I get the following error:

> "InvalidOperationException: SslCredentials with non-null arguments is not supported by GrpcChannel. GrpcChannel uses HttpClient to make gRPC calls and HttpClient automatically loads root certificates from the operating system certificate store. Client certificates should be configured on HttpClient. See https://aka.ms/aspnet/grpc/certauth for details."

My server is setup with the following setup:

```
let cacert = File.ReadAllText(@"ca.crt");
let servercert = File.ReadAllText(@"server.crt");
let serverkey = File.ReadAllText(@"server.key");

let certificatePair = new KeyCertificatePair(servercert, serverkey);
let certList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<KeyCertificatePair>()
    certList.Add(certificatePair)
let server = new Server()
    server.Services.Add(EventSubscriberService.EventSubscriberServiceMethodBinder.BindService(new EventSubscriber()))
    server.Ports.Add(new ServerPort("localhost", 5001,SslServerCredentials(certList,cacert,false))) 
    |> ignore'''
```

And the client uses this setup:

```
let cacert = File.ReadAllText(@"ca.crt");
let clientcert = File.ReadAllText(@"client.crt");
let clientkey = File.ReadAllText(@"client.key");
let ssl = new SslCredentials(cacert, new KeyCertificatePair(clientcert, clientkey))

let channelOptions = GrpcChannelOptions()
channelOptions.HttpHandler <- new WinHttpHandler()    
channelOptions.Credentials <- ssl


let channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://127.0.0.1:5001",channelOptions)
```

It is written in F#, but resembles this C# code, if reference helps readability. [How to enable server side SSL for gRPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714558/how-to-enable-server-side-ssl-for-grpc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something along the following lines (rough draft) should work:

```
open System.Net.Http
open Grpc.Net.Client
open System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

let clientCert = new X509Certificate() // create according to your needs
let handler = new HttpClientHandler()
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCert) |> ignore
// insecure, check your custom server cert
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback <- fun msg cert chain e -> true
let client = new HttpClient(handler)
let channelOptions = GrpcChannelOptions(HttpClient = client)
let channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://127.0.0.1:5001", channelOptions)
```

Comment: Seems to do the trick. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here as @CaringDev wrote, but for C# :

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Grpc.Net.Client;

namespace IntegrationTests
{
    public class Class
    {
        public void Method()
        {
            var clientCert = new X509Certificate();
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCert);
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
            var client = new HttpClient(handler);
            var channelOptions = new GrpcChannelOptions() { HttpClient = client };
            var channel = Grpc.Net.Client.GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://127.0.0.1:5001", channelOptions);
        }

        public void Or_GrpcCore_InsteadOf_GrpcNetClient_Namespace()
        {
            /* For HTTP 1 / 1.1 Use Obsolete "Grpc.Core" */
            var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(host: "localhost", port: 5001,
                ChannelCredentials.Insecure,
                new ChannelOption[]
                {
                    new ChannelOption(global::Grpc.Core.ChannelOptions.MaxReceiveMessageLength, int.MaxValue)
                });
        }
    }
}
```